# Select items with specific field values from a list of dictionaries (similar to SQL SELECT command)

Tags: python, sql, list, select, dictionary

Suppose we have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
mylist=[{'word':'bear','category':'animal'},
        {'word':'lion','category':'animal'},
        {'word':'ant','category':'insect'},
        {'word':'ladybug','category':'insect'}]
```

I want to select items with `'category':'animal'` into a new list like what I usually do in a mockup SQL:`SELECT * FROM mylist WHERE 'category'='insect'`.

The **outcome** will be:

```
newlist=[{'word':'ant','category':'insect'},
        {'word':'ladybug','category':'insect'}]
```

How can I do this in Python 2.7 ? I know I could do this using a `for` loop (everyone knows that :) ), but I guess there is a more clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with an "if" statement to do it pretty quickly.

Your original list object:

```
mylist=[{'word':'bear','category':'animal'},
        {'word':'lion','category':'animal'},
        {'word':'ant','category':'insect'},
        {'word':'ladybug','category':'insect'}]
```

List comprehension to create your new list object where the "category" key has a value of "insect":

```
newlist = [dict for dict in mylist if dict["category"] == "insect"]
```

Result:

```
[{'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ant'},
{'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ladybug'}]
```

The listed dictionary objects will automatically sort themselves alphabetically by key, but the answer is still the same structurally.  I hope this helps!

Comment: What's the reason that the objects will automatically sort themselves alphabetically ?

Comment: I think is was the way that the data structure was first conceptualized.  It should not matter too much though because you are relying on string indexes and not integer indexes to loop through your data.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newlist = [item for item in mylist if item['category'] == 'insect']
```

This loops over all elements in your input list, including only those that match the `if` expression.

Demo:

```
>>> mylist=[{'word':'bear','category':'animal'},
...         {'word':'lion','category':'animal'},
...         {'word':'ant','category':'insect'},
...         {'word':'ladybug','category':'insect'}]
>>> [item for item in mylist if item['category'] == 'insect']
[{'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ant'}, {'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ladybug'}]
>>> [item for item in mylist if item['category'] == 'animal']
[{'category': 'animal', 'word': 'bear'}, {'category': 'animal', 'word': 'lion'}]
>>> [item for item in mylist if item['word'] in ('bear', 'ladybug')]
[{'category': 'animal', 'word': 'bear'}, {'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ladybug'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
newlist=[x for x in mylist if x['category']=='animal']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional style solution without *explicitly* coding a `for` loop.

Define a function that will return a boolean comparing a dictionary value to a specified value.

```
import functools, pprint
def foo(d, key, value):
    return d[key] == value
```

Use `functools.partial` to create *filters* to your requirements

```
# category filter
animal = functools.partial(foo, key = 'category', value = 'animal')
# word filter
ant = functools.partial(foo, key = 'word', value = 'ant')
```

Use those *filters* throughout your program:

```
pprint.pprint(filter(animal, mylist))

>>>
[{'category': 'animal', 'word': 'bear'},
 {'category': 'animal', 'word': 'lion'}]
>>>

pprint(filter(ant, mylist))

>>>
[{'category': 'insect', 'word': 'ant'}]
>>>
```